# Executing Different Parts of JavaScript Code by Pressing Key and Clicking

Tags: javascript

I have code for 3 different task which I want to execute by clicking and pressing a key, so there will be 3 different combination of clicking and pressing. For example-

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
if(e.keyCode === 16) {console.log('Yap! Shift works...');}


if(e.keyCode === 17) {console.log('Yap! Ctrl works...');
document.addEventListener('click',function (event) {
console.log(event.target.className); 
}, false);
          }     

 },false);
```

Now, when I press click shift key, I get related output, when I click `Ctrl` key and then click, I get the class name of the object I click on.

But the problem is, the output keeps coming as much I hold the key!! I want to execute the part of my code for once, and exactly when the key is pressed and a clicked is occurred.

How can I do that?

In general, how can I execute 3 part of  code for three different tasks by clicking and pressing efficiently?

Comment: Hi Mike, not sure if I got your question correct, but it seems that you add your click handler the first time CTRL is pressed but you don't remove it on "keyup". So every click from now on triggers the click event.

Comment: @JohannesStadler  probably .. what should I do?? can you change my code and post it as answer?

Comment: See @giuseppedeponte answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an event handler *while* handing an event, is often the wrong way to solve a problem. Imagine how you will accumulate adding handlers... in your case there will eventually be many bindings to the same click handler.

It is better to bind the handlers you need *immediately*, and then work with keeping state on what exactly needs to happen while handling the event.

In these key handlers (`keydown`, `keyup`), keep track of whether the Shift/Control keys are depressed or not.

Also, use `e.key` as `e.keyCode` is deprecated.

Here is how that could work:

```js
let keys = {
    "Shift": false,
    "Control": false
};
function keyToggle(e) {
    if (!(e.key in keys)) return; // not ctrl or shift
    let isKeyDown = e.type === "keydown";
    if (isKeyDown === keys[e.key]) return; // key position did not change
    keys[e.key] = isKeyDown;
    console.log(e.key + (isKeyDown ? " pressed" : " released"));        
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyToggle, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyToggle, false);
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (keys["Control"]) console.log(event.target.className); 
}, false);
```

```html
<main class="main">Main</main>
<aside class="aside">Aside</aside>
```

Comment: I am having some trouble to get the logic of the code, why`` keyup`` and ``keydown`` are used with false, I mean in ``document.addEventListener("keydown", keyToggle, false); document.addEventListener("keyup", keyToggle, false); `` why either key up or key down is not used ??

Comment: The third argument passed to `addEventListener` is not that important here. It has to do with event bubbling. It could be left out, as `false` is the default value.

The difference between keyup/keydown is made in the `keyToggle` function itself, which reads out the value of `e.key`, and that will determine the value of `isKeyDown`. If it was a keydown event, `isKeyDown` with be `true`, if it was another event (keyup), then it will be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

As you `addEventListener` you can also `removeEventListener`.

For that you need a reference to your event handler, so you cannot use anonymous functions, but named functions or functions stored in a variable.

**Edit**
Here is an example of using CTRL+click:

```js
// CTRL + CLICK implementation
let hasCtrl = false;
// Store the handler in a constant or variable
const handleClick = function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.className);
}
// Use named function
function handleKeyDown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 16) {
    console.log('Yap! Shift works...');
  }
}

const setCtrlInactive = (e) => {
  if (!hasCtrl && e.keyCode === 17) {
    console.log('Nope! Ctrl does not work...');
    document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    hasCtrl = true;
  }
}
const setCtrlActive = (e) => {
  if (hasCtrl && e.keyCode === 17) {
    console.log('Yap! Ctrl works...');
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    hasCtrl = false;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", setCtrlInactive);
document.addEventListener("keydown", setCtrlActive);


document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
```

```html
<main class="main">Main</main>
<aside class="aside">Aside</aside>
```

Comment: Once you use CTRL+click you can not use Shift key, which is not what i am looking for..

Comment: That was just an exemple on how to remove an event listener. Feel free to call it wherever in your code you see fit

Answer (score 0):

Well you can easily create an variable to lock it:

```
var locked = false;
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
if(e.keyCode === 16 && !locked) {console.log('Yap! Shift works...'); locked = 
true;}


if(e.keyCode === 17 && !locked ) {console.log('Yap! Ctrl works...');
locked = true;

      }     

},false);

document.addEventListener('click',function (event) {
if(locked){
// do something
console.log(event.target.className); 
}
}, false);

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
   locked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you called `addEventListener('click')` in the keydown event handler.

```js
let ctrl = false;

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 16) {
    console.log('Yap! Shift works...');
  }

  if (e.keyCode === 17 && ctrl === false) {
    console.log('Yap! Ctrl works...');
    ctrl = true;
  }

});

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode === 17) {
    ctrl = false;
  }

});

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (ctrl) {
    console.log(event.target.className);
  }
}, false);
```

Instead, you should use keyup event and flag variable.